# List all the elements in a python namespace

Tags: python, function, class, namespaces

Python classes contain namespaces and the function [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) lists the content of the namespace.

The `object` namespace contains several functions, for example the function `__subclasses__` that, when invoked, returns a list containing all the known classes that are subclasses of `object`.

The output of `dir(object)` is:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__',
 '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

The `__subclasses__` function is not listed, but it's there, try: `object.__subclasses__()`.

I understand that a class can change the `__dir__` dictionary to customize what `dir` shows, but that's not the case of `object`, in fact `object.__dir__` raises an exception.

Still, when I use IPython autocompletion, the `__subclasses__` function is there. How can I obtain the same list of elements that IPython uses so that I know that also `__subclasses__` is there?

Comment: "Python classes are just namespaces" - no they're not.

Comment: @user2357112: Could you elaborate a bit? From the python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) I read: *When a class definition is left normally (via the end), a class object is created. This is basically a wrapper around the contents of the namespace created by the class definition;*

Comment: While a class object does wrap the namespace of the class statement, saying that a class is just a namespace is like saying a human is just a left leg. The namespace is only part of the class.

Comment: @user2357112: this makes sense, but still, a human is not even "basically a wrapper of his left leg". I understand that it's semantically biased to say that "it is just", but still, according to the documentation the namespace should be its prevalent component.

Comment: @user2357112: By the way you are right, so I'll improve the question, thanks ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IPython finds `__subclasses__` through perfectly ordinary means, by looking at `type(object)`. On the other hand, since `object` is a type, [`dir` for types](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/object.c#l1812) specifically does not look at `type(object)`. Whoever wrote `dir` decided seeing metaclass attributes in the list would be confusing.